# how to give name for Zend_Form

Tags: zend-framework, zend-form

Hi i am new to zendframework , i creating a form using Zend_Form();
i need to give a name for that form. i try the below but not works

ex1:
$form = new Zend_Form();
$form->setMethod('post')
->setName('add_to_mail')// give name like this 
->setAttrib('id', 'add_to_mail');

ex2:

$form = new Zend_Form();
$form->setMethod('post')
->setAttrib('name', 'add_to_mail'); // give name in attribute

Please any one help me .. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

```
$form = new Zend_Form();
$form->setMethod('post');
$form->setName('MyFormName');
```

should do it

Answer (score 3):

```
$form = new Zend_Form(array(
    'name' => 'MyFormName'
));
```

Answer (score 1):

can set the name by

```
$form->setName('registration');
```

can retreive the name by

```
$name = $form->getName();
```